# Prevent database duplicates in RubyOnRails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

This is a SAAS solution with many customers.
We receiving a lot of reservations via Webpush for many different properties, when the reservation was created or changed on the other side.

Sometimes it happens, a new entry was created, and 30ms later, we receive an update.
Then our current approach fails sometimes. Currently we're just using a simple lock to prevent changes at the same time. But the `find_or_create_by!`-Method before might be the problem which creates duplicates.

```rb
reservation = reservations.reload.find_or_create_by!(hotel_id: hotel.id, reservation_id: api_reservation.id, booking_id: api_reservation.booking_id)
reservation.with_lock { update_reservation(reservation, api_reservation) }
```

To prevent changes at the same time for one reservation, we just build a reservation with minimal data, which will be updated afterwards in the lock.
In the update, there will be some information added besides of the data from the creation. So the information from the initial creation are in the update als included.

To prevent duplicates, we added a validation in the model.
But there are some cases, where duplicates are okay, for example when there is no connection to a hotel system and the guest fills out the information by himself. So there are hundreds of reservations with the reservation_id "0000" oder "1234",... because the guest doesn't know the correct number often.

```rb
class Reservation
  validates :reservation_id, uniqueness: { scope: [:hotel_id, :booking_id] }, if: :to_be_uniq?
end
```

So there is currently no possibilty to validate this with a PostgreSQL Unique index.

With that ruby validation we had the strange problem, that we created the reservation and then the update failed, because the reservation already exists.
`RuntimeError - ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Reservation has already been taken`
When I checked the database, the error was a false positive.

We removed the validation because it caused more problems than it solved.

My last idea is to put random information into the reservations which are created manually. Then it would be possible to validate this via the unique index in PostgreSQL.

But I can't understand, why an update with the same data, raises the Validation Error.
Does someone have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Rails provides only low-level locking using `SELECT … FOR UPDATE` and other lock types.
It means that when you use `with_lock` it only locks current record, in your case `reservation`.
You need to lock all table while operation with the record is being processed.

Example:

```rb
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('LOCK reservations IN ACCESS EXCLUSIVE MODE')

  reservation = reservations.reload.find_or_create_by!(hotel_id: hotel.id, reservation_id: api_reservation.id, booking_id: api_reservation.booking_id)
  update_reservation(reservation, api_reservation)
end
```

**Update**

If locking table isn't the option you can use **rescue**

```rb
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  begin
    reservation = reservations.reload.find_or_create_by!(hotel_id: hotel.id, reservation_id: api_reservation.id, booking_id: api_reservation.booking_id)
    update_reservation(reservation, api_reservation)
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
    # your saving logic goes here
  end 
end
```

Comment: It's no solution to lock the entire table, we're receving every second a buch of reservations, so this will cause a huge backlog of processes wairing to write into the database.

Comment: For such small query locking table will take milliseconds and it shouldn't cause huge backlog of waiting processes. But if locking table isn't the option in your case than you can use rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid and process your unsaved record in this block

Comment: The Reserveration table is heavy frequent in use. so therefore I don't wat to lock it.
I've tried to lock the hotel, so that only one reservation per hotel can be processed at the same time. This created a backlog of 30000 locks. 
Wen I chat that part to that solution you've updated, I will get the problems again, that an existing reservertion can't be updated, because it's a duplicate, although there is only one reservation.